# How do I make this strict with typescript types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make CSS prop object to be a strict subset of only certain CSS properties but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Can someone please help me?

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

interface HeadingProps {
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  className?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  css?: Pick<React.CSSProperties, 'margin'>;
}

const Heading = ({ children, ...others }: HeadingProps) => {
  return (
    <h1
      style={others.style}
      className={others.className}
      css={{ color: 'blue' }}>
      {children}
    </h1>
  );
};

// This should fail because of `css?: Pick<React.CSSProperties, 'margin'>` .. but for some reason
// it doesn't error
const style = {
  margin: 120,
  background: 'red',
};

render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <div
      css={{ margin: 32, color: 'green', display: 'grid', background: 'pink' }}>
      <Heading aria-label="Sd" css={style}>
        I am a Heading
      </Heading>
    </div>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

[Typescript URL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?checkJs=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzlApgOwCYqnAvnAMyghDgHJUBDAYxgFoMSyBuAKFEljgCUUb4iJclVotWrLNQA2lVHBAQMAVykphfUYlZwdcYGhjYCNNQBEA8gFkAgjBhRgAIyWGAzgB4AKgD4tu-3DUrq4A-ABcPBowAHQAwgDK8QAKxGDYMMAortq6uKx57AZGJnAAEnwY+gDmKRBgrn5wrjAAnqrhkfxxibVpsJmubDrSlMEAcpQgKB3NDmhVQ4EAFsBSGKhoEbxd27RjiiiLQaERScDUANbuuzEJyanpAwA05CCyVfpk3mwF1BBozTKFWqcAAvHAABRIagrNYbF7RREQGBLbANXARcqUSrzXquACUYN8CByqBgSigaEhOR07iWAEYabpmm0UKCEMjUVBXNEWao8gFAjJxpM2RyUWjoiMRVMBQFjuzoRApNAImRHFIlCgyHhcN4mToEDDVut0HLaQB6Bn6nT4n5sVgWi1wTwrBquJYQFQYQiUVZwRwoaiUJSuNQQAhwAAGxw6Z0u1yi3XudUeWReZDeUA+aC+UbgiIDLkI0CaJDUVFc-0dzuA8EYWVz8GwxCgrD+APgfLU4JJOizOYi9IATAAGJ45Rw0C5VYhKTBq1AYMgT3AOjZYKAQnKJrrxeznGCWA423TuSoANwNgWCivk730EQAzMOXn8VVA1bOUOgV3BKq4YAyC0X4OMuLxTpcs5egu5BgPoFw6rgerXu4WI4lUcCyMAlB0DIgZSKCABE8QYERN6uOy3YoYKOgAJJYaQlBAti1SoRa6HVKelqXqe7gWjc0T7g4tDHlg3gTjojDUEoUwGNEVQoDAACiqhyTAABCLR0RgEJkJQYBgGQ+KsHaQA)

Comment: What, specifically, does *"it doesn't seem to work for some reason"* mean?

Comment: @kaya3 if I pass the same object as inline instead of referencing using a variable, it shows an error.

Comment: What error? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> // This should fail because of `css?: Pick<React.CSSProperties, 'margin'>` .. but for some reason
> // it doesn't error
>
> const style = {
> margin: 120,
> background: 'red',
> };

There are no types on this line, so it's impossible for anything to fail here. Typescript will simply look at what you've written, and infer a type from it (in this case, it infers the type to be `{ margin: number, background: string }`.

If you give this an explicit type, then typescript will check against that, so you could introduce a failure by doing the following:

```
const style: Pick<React.CSSProperties, 'margin'> = {
  margin: 120,
  background: 'red'
}
```

Later on, you do this:

```
css={style}
```

There's no error here either, because the types are compatible. You've said you need to be passed in an object with a margin property that's a `string | number | undefined`, and then you're passing in one with `margin: number`, which matches. The object does have other properties too, but typescript is designed to allow that, since you're supposed to be able to pass a subclass in where a base class is called for (and subclasses often have additional properties that the base class does not).

Comment: Thx for answer .. is it possible to restrict additional properties & without explicitly typing the style object?I like to replicate [same as flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBdkwBDAZzACUBTUgY2KnzizAHJ87H2BudVIQCeOGmAASdACYYAdgHMACixyUAvGADeqMGHoALDDCldZALmrdCAOgBycKTQA0O+uXIB+MBc0AfHbpYpPjych4WsgCuWABGNPg6vgC+qEn8qPRwsuTEkqQyCmAaABSaeu5OeobGpmBJFnkFSirkAJRFAHxaAVyEkfiyYAA8+gCM5eRqmm7kSR0ButPVJjSyKbrDwGPzKRlZOWA5QjBiGmVBIXIWAEwALJUxDADW8iyRslIWnDRS7HXpmWyxAAgjgcEUwMV2moutpdL1+oMhvNdMBgGAAOoEJ7kBbDRpyeQTKbnYKhcxgO51OYASTIbAJhSGwEZ8hRGzRYHsojxQ1ZxM0RxOtPpEmkhM2rPZzJ2QA)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different way to achieve what you are after but personally I would not restrict myself from using CSS properties:

```js
import { render } from "react-dom";
import React, { ReactNode, CSSProperties } from "react";

interface HeadingProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  css?: {
    margin: CSSProperties["margin"];
  };
}

const Heading = ({ children, css }: HeadingProps) => (
  <h1 style={css}>{children}</h1>
);

render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Heading css={{ margin: 10 }}>Works</Heading>
    <Heading css={{ margin: 10, background: "red" }}>Error</Heading>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-night-mj18i?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: HeadingTwo is closer to what you are after

Comment: Thanks Alex ...even I was able to accomplish like you did above .. but wondering if it could be done without explicitly typing the `style` variable

Comment: I like to replicate flow here https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBdkwBDAZzACUBTUgY2KnzizAHJ87H2BudVIQCeOGmAASdACYYAdgHMACixyUAvGADeqMGHoALDDCldZALmrdCAOgBycKTQA0O+uXIB+MBc0AfHbpYpPjych4WsgCuWABGNPg6vgC+qEn8qPRwsuTEkqQyCmAaABSaeu5OeobGpmBJFnkFSirkAJRFAHxaAVyEkfiyYAA8+gCM5eRqmm7kSR0ButPVJjSyKbrDwGPzKRlZOWA5QjBiGmVBIXIWAEwALJUxDADW8iyRslIWnDRS7HXpmWyxAAgjgcEUwMV2moutpdL1+oMhvNdMBgGAAOoEJ7kBbDRpyeQTKbnYKhcxgO51OYASTIbAJhSGwEZ8hRGzRYHsojxQ1ZxM0RxOtPpEmkhM2rPZzJ2QA .. without explicitly typing the style variable

Comment: I don't think you read my answer correctly. I've removed non-essential code and written it as close the flow example you provided as possible.